# Celery from CreateAPIView with DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, celery

I have set up Celery for my Django project to handle background tasks. However, I am struggling to ensure that when creating an event, there is a 60-second sleep delay in the background without blocking the request.

Here is my relevant code:

```
models.py:

class Event(models.Model):
    # Fields description

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'Мероприятие'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Мероприятия'


serializers.py:


class EventCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organizations = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Organization.objects.all(),
        many=True,
        required=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'organizations', 'date', 'image')

views.py:

class EventCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    """
    Create a new event.
    """
    serializer_class = EventCreateSerializer
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

lthough the EventCreateView works fine, the task seems to be executed instantly, and the object is created without the intended delay. What modifications do I need to make to ensure the 60-second sleep delay is applied correctly?

`

```
tasks.py:

from celery import shared_task
from time import sleep
from .models import Event

@shared_task
def async_task(event_id):
    sleep(60)
    event = Event.objects.get(pk=event_id)
    print(f'Async task completed for event with ID {event_id}')
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can try to take a look at providing `countdown` when orchestrating a task for the future https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown